# How to see if wxpython is installed?

Tags: 12.04, python

I would like to know how can i determine if wxpython is installed on ubuntu 12.04?

And i would like to know as well if ubuntu 12.04 already has wxpython installed by default?

Answer (score 2):

To see if wxpython is installed we may try to import it in the Python interpreter:

```
>>> import wx
```

In a script, we can also check for wxpython with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

try:
    import wx
except ImportError:
    print('wxpython is not installed')
```

In Ubuntu wxpython is not installed by default but we can easily install the basic Python modules (need 35.1 MB of disk space)  with:

```
sudo apt-get install python-wxgtk2.8 python-wxtools
```

Still, additional packages may be needed for other applications. For further details on this also see

- [wxPyWiki - Installing on Ubuntu or Debian](http://wiki.wxpython.org/InstallingOnUbuntuOrDebian)

Comment: I was under the impression that it was python3 because of the `print()` syntax

Comment: I got so much used to `print()` in my code to make it run on both, python2 and python3 ;)

Answer (score 1):

`whereis wxpython` will show you if it's installed, and https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/department/precise/accessories/?page=32 does not show it as included in the default executables. You may also find this page useful in installing it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007557/installing-wxpython-on-ubuntu-12-04